# Need advice with creating right query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I need some advice with creating right query. Let's say I have file with multiple names, this file will be updated every day and I want to run UPDATE query but only in rows WHERE name = these names, is this even possible? I was thinking about arrays, but I don't know if it's possible, as you can see I'm not that good in sql(:D).

Comment: " is this even possible?" yes.

Comment: We need to know more than this to be able to give an answer. What is the table structure you are updating? What fields are you trying to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator, for example if you wanted to update all Users where their id was either 10, 15, or 20, you can do

`UPDATE Users SET ... WHERE id IN (10,15,20)`

The same thing can be done for string fields:

`UPDATE Users SET ... WHERE username in ('john','bob','tammy')`